# What is the difference between Ganapadigal and Deekshathirs?

Tags: vedas, puranas, advaita, adi-shankaracharya, smarta

Can someone tell me the difference between Ganapadigal and Deekshithirs?

Both are smarthas, right? What is the difference between the two sects?

Comment: Prakrithi(fundamental) and vikrrithi(derived) are the two classes of recitation styles (paathas) of veda mantras.Prakriti is further classified into samhita paatha(chant without breaking the words in sandhis),padha paatha(chant by breaking the words in sandhi) and Krama paatha(joining two words at a time).Ghana is one of the kinds of vikrrithi, like, where first two words are chanted in sequence, then they are reversed first 3 in sequence then reversed, 1.2 , 2.1 , 1.2.3 , 3.2.1 , 1.2.3 , 2.3 ,3.2 , 2.3.4 , 4.3.2 , 2.3.4 , 3.4, 4.3 , 3.4.5  and so on . .

Comment: Ghanapaathi is a one , who has mastered upto the stage of Ghana..If a Dikshitar has mastered upto Ghana style of recitation then he is known as Ghanapaathi

Comment: @Athrey, thank you very much for the clarification. Could you just write an answer for this question? It'd be very helpful.